# How to increase the speed in loop in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, performance, for-loop

I have a code which is taking almost 8 sec to execute, I want to do it below 1 sec. Any tips to increase the speed will be highly appreciated.

```vb
Parallel.ForEach(gOutputElements_2D, 
    Sub(number)
        number.Stress1 = LC.stresses.Find(Function(c) c.Tag0D = number.FirstNode.Tag AndAlso c.Tag2D = number.Tag)
        number.Stress2 = LC.stresses.Find(Function(c) c.Tag0D = number.SecondNode.Tag AndAlso c.Tag2D = number.Tag)
        number.Stress3 = LC.stresses.Find(Function(c) c.Tag0D = number.ThirdNode.Tag AndAlso c.Tag2D = number.Tag)
    End Sub)
```

gOutputElements_2D is a list, contains about 10000 items, while LC.stresses contains about 30000 items.

Comment: Does it run faster if you don't do it in parallel? (There is overhead to setting up parallel operations.) What is the type of the `.Tag` property? Have you tried swapping the operands for the `AndAlso`s? Have you tried writing it without LINQ?

Comment: @AndrewMorton If i use simple for loop, it is taking almost 24 sec i.e. three times more. .Tag property is an integer.
can you please show me how to write it without LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       Parallel.ForEach(gOutputElements_2D,
Sub(number)
    Dim found As Integer = 0
    For Each c As clsMSHStress In LC.stresses
        If c.Tag2D = number.Tag Then
            If c.Tag0D = number.FirstNode.Tag Then
                number.Stress1 = c
                found += 1
            End If
            If c.Tag0D = number.SecondNode.Tag Then
                number.Stress2 = c
                found += 1
            End If
            If c.Tag0D = number.ThirdNode.Tag Then
                number.Stress3 = c
                found += 1
            End If
        End If
        If found = 3 Then Exit For
    Next
End Sub)
```

I achieved my goals through this in about 1 to 2 sec.

Comment: This will give you the LAST match for each, until all three have a match. I don't know what your data is like, so this may not happen, but it could theoretically.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was hoping to encourage you to investigate with my comment on your question :) If you need people to try to find a faster way (which might not be possible), you could try asking over on Code Review, but please explain what the data represents, in case there are any optimisations that can come from that.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your using LINQ in this case is causing it to take three times longer than it should, since you basically have three loops where you could use one. You could try this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(gOutputElements_2D, 
    Sub(number)
        Dim found As Integer = 0
        For Each c In LC.stresses
            If c.Tag2D = number.Tag Then
                If c.Tag0D = number.FirstNode.Tag AndAlso (found And 1) Then
                    number.Stress1 = c
                    found = found Or 1
                End If
                If c.Tag0D = number.SecondNode.Tag AndAlso (found And 2) Then
                    number.Stress2 = c
                    found = found Or 2
                End If
                If c.Tag0D = number.ThirdNode.Tag AndAlso (found And 4) Then
                    number.Stress1 = c
                    found = found Or 4
                End If
            End If
            If found And 7 Then Exit For
        Next
    End Sub)
```

This should set your variables to the first instance of each found, and then exit early when all of them are found.

Comment: I managed to do this in about 1.5 sec now. I have made a little changes in your suggested code. Thank you for your help